# Visual glitch in FTB Revelation with SEUS Renewal shaders

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing FTB Revelation installed through TLauncher. I also installed SEUS Renewal shader pack through Tlauncher.

This glitch with shadows that appear in some angles and disappear in other is happening to me.

I'm playing minecraft 1.12.2

I was just rotating, not moving, and I was taking screenshots to demonstrate it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It's annoying and I don't know how to resolve it.
I tried to turn off cloud, but it did not help. Is there a way how to fix it and get rid of this glitch?

Answer (score 1):

The glitch is caused by collision between Botania shaders and SEUS shaders.
Setting `B:shaders.enabled=false` in `config/botania.cfg` and reloading whole game after this changed solved the issue.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/8ldx02/random_shadows_with_shaders/